Getting Catastrophic failure installing WSL Windows 10
I had installed WSL in my windows 10 since about 5 years ago in my PhD thesis to work with torch and it was ok. Now I need Linux again for using compute Canada clusters. the WSL was appeared in the start menu but when I clicked nothing happened.
Therefore I tried to install it again using WSL --install command and it give some help like message about the usage of WSL command like this:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [CommandLine]

Arguments for running Linux binaries:

    If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.

    --exec, -e <CommandLine>
        Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.

    --
        Pass the remaining command line as is.

Options:
    --cd <Directory>
        Sets the specified directory as the current working directory.
        If ~ is used the Linux user's home path will be used. If the path begins
        with a / character, it will be interpreted as an absolute Linux path.
        Otherwise, the value must be an absolute Windows path.

    --distribution, -d <Distro>
        Run the specified distribution.

    --user, -u <UserName>
        Run as the specified user.

Arguments for managing Windows Subsystem for Linux:

    --help
        Display usage information.

    --install [Options]
        Install additional Windows Subsystem for Linux distributions.
        For a list of valid distributions, use 'wsl --list --online'.

        Options:
            --distribution, -d [Argument]
                Downloads and installs a distribution by name.

                Arguments:
                    A valid distribution name (not case sensitive).

                Examples:
                    wsl --install -d Ubuntu
                    wsl --install --distribution Debian

    --set-default-version <Version>
        Changes the default install version for new distributions.

    --shutdown
        Immediately terminates all running distributions and the WSL 2
        lightweight utility virtual machine.

    --status
        Show the status of Windows Subsystem for Linux.

    --update [Options]
        If no options are specified, the WSL 2 kernel will be updated
        to the latest version.

        Options:
            --rollback
                Revert to the previous version of the WSL 2 kernel.

            --inbox
                Only update the inbox WSL 2 kernel. Do not install WSL from the Microsoft Store.

            --web-download
                Download the most recent version of WSL from the internet instead of the Microsoft Store.

Arguments for managing distributions in Windows Subsystem for Linux:

    --export <Distro> <FileName>
        Exports the distribution to a tar file.
        The filename can be - for standard output.

    --import <Distro> <InstallLocation> <FileName> [Options]
        Imports the specified tar file as a new distribution.
        The filename can be - for standard input.

        Options:
            --version <Version>
                Specifies the version to use for the new distribution.

    --list, -l [Options]
        Lists distributions.

        Options:
            --all
                List all distributions, including distributions that are
                currently being installed or uninstalled.

            --running
                List only distributions that are currently running.

            --quiet, -q
                Only show distribution names.

            --verbose, -v
                Show detailed information about all distributions.

            --online, -o
                Displays a list of available distributions for install with 'wsl --install'.

    --set-default, -s <Distro>
        Sets the distribution as the default.

    --set-version <Distro> <Version>
        Changes the version of the specified distribution.

    --terminate, -t <Distro>
        Terminates the specified distribution.

    --unregister <Distro>
        Unregisters the distribution and deletes the root filesystem.

and when I try
wsl --update
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Catastrophic failure happens.
I have tried the solutions in the web like running powershell as administrator or uncheck the element in windows systwm and delete wsl from Appdata but nothing works. Any help will be welcoming

I fixed the problem.

In the search bar, search for turn windows features on or off.
Make sure these three options are checked: windows subsystem for linux, virtual machine platform, windows hypervisor platform


Unfortunately, it didn't work. When I type wsl in power shell I get:
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore and wsl --install still gives the same help like output

I had the same issue with wsl --install showing the help message. Specifying a distribution directly worked for me:
wsl --install -d Ubuntu

This successfully installed and launched Ubuntu. You can list available distributions with:
wsl --list --online

If wsl --update gives a catastrophic failure, try these steps:

Update Windows fully.
Re-enable Windows Subsystem for Linux in Turn Windows Features on or off.
Run wsl --update --web-download in PowerShell as Administrator.

Let me know if it worked!

Thank you actually  wsl --install -d Ubuntu got error : An error occurred during installation. Distribution Name: 'Debian GNU/Linux' Error Code: 0x8000ffff, but wsl --update --web-download worked and I could install wsl on my system. But after this successful  installation, wsl --install -d Ubuntu gives catastrophic failure again: Catastrophic failure
Error code: Wsl/InstallDistro/E_UNEXPECTED
